# How do I pass a variable number of arguments to a LLVM opt pass?

Tags: c++, clang, llvm

I want to pass a variable number of arguments to my LLVM opt pass.

To do this, I do something like:

```
static cl::list<std::string> Files(cl::Positional, cl::OneOrMore);
static cl::list<std::string> Libraries("l", cl::ZeroOrMore);
```

However, if I now invoke opt like:

```
foo@foo-Ubuntu:~/llvm-ir-obfuscation$ opt -load cmake-build-debug/water/libMapInstWMPass.so -mapiWM programs/ll/sum100.ll -S 2 3 4  -o foo.ll
opt: Too many positional arguments specified!
Can specify at most 2 positional arguments: See: opt -help
```

, then I get errors that opt will accept at most 2 positional arguments.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The S flag is not an option to the pass, it is an option to opt itself making it output LLVM assembly.

Comment: How can I make the first work (Positional)?

Comment: Can you explain the '-mapiWM' option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that `opt` is already parsing its own arguments, and has already the bitcode file to process as a positional argument, so having more than one positional arguments creates ambiguity.

The documentation explains the API as if it is used in a standalone application. So, for example, if you do something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  cl::list<std::string> Files(cl::Positional, cl::OneOrMore);
  cl::list<std::string> Files2(cl::Positional, cl::OneOrMore);
  cl::list<std::string> Libraries("l", cl::ZeroOrMore);
  cl::ParseCommandLineOptions(argc, argv);

  for(auto &e : Libraries) outs() << e << "\n";
  outs() << "....\n";
  for(auto &e : Files) outs() << e << "\n";
  outs() << "....\n";
  for(auto &e : Files2) outs() << e << "\n";
  outs() << "....\n";
}
```

you get something like this:

```
$ foo -l one two three four five six

one
....
two
three
four
five
....
six
....
```

Now, if you swap around the two positional argument definitions, or even change the `cl::OneOrMore` of `Files2` option to `cl::ZeroOrMore`, you will get an error

```
$ option: error - option can never match, because another positional argument will match an unbounded number of values, and this option does not require a value!
```

Personally, when I use `opt` I forego the positiontal argument option and do something like this:

```
cl::list<std::string> Lists("lists", cl::desc("Specify names"), cl::OneOrMore);
```

which allows me to do this:

```
opt -load ./fooPass.so -foo -o out.bc -lists one ./in.bc -lists two
```

and iterating over the `std::string` list the same way I get:

```
one
two
```

Comment: Thanks dude! As a last question, before I mark your answer as accepted: do you know how to see the option descriptions for a pass outputted on the terminal? How do I tell `opt` to list, e.g., `cl::desc("Specify names")` for my pass?

Comment: doesn't `-help` do that for you? as stated [here](http://llvm.org/docs/CommandLine.html#cl-desc)

Comment: No, it just lists the help menu for `opt` - not the pass itself.

Comment: you still need to load the pass's shared object with `-load`

Comment: Could you provide a sample command-line with output? Just in case I do something wrong.

Comment: unless you've played around with `cl::Hidden` it should be visible with `-help` by executing `opt -load ./foo.so -foo -help | grep Specify` I get
 `-lists=<string>                                                - Specify names
`

Comment: Here, `foo` is the name of your pass?

Comment: yeah, that's how I registered it.

Answer (score 2):

As @compor suggests, this probably has something to do with intertwining arguments for `opt` and your own pass. The CommandLine library is primarily written for standalone applications within the LLVM framework.

However, you can do something like:

```
static cl::list<std::string> Args1("args1", cl::Positional, cl::CommaSeparated);
static cl::list<std::string> Args2("args2", cl::ZeroOrMore);
```

This has the advantage that you can input multiple arguments on the command-line using either commas, e.g., `arg1,arg2,...` or by using the identifier `-args1 arg1 arg2 ...`; and these get inserted into the `Args1` list. If you just supply a single positional argument `arg` on the command line, then `Args1` will contain this argument only.

Also, you can specify `-args2 arg` on the command-line wherever you with (named non-positional option). These will go into the `Args2` list.